# How can I create a secure microsite?

Tags: permissions, marketing-cloud, microsites

We have several forms hosted in a microsite which are used to add/update records to data extensions. We need to secure these so that unauthorized parties can't access the forms.

Is it easy to secure forms created on a microsite to limit access to only those authorized users in exacttarget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each page allows for a specific type of security setting you can set in the page's properties.

According to the [docs](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-GB/documentation/exacttarget/content/microsites/landing_pages/):

- Security - Determines whether you require users to log in to see this landing page.
  Available to all visitors - no credentials are required to access the landing page once it is running.
- Application Users Only - a user must be logged in to this email marketing application in order to access the landing page. If the user is not logged in, the browser displays an error.
- System Authenticated Redirection - a user must be logged into this email marketing application using this authentication process in order to access the landing page. If the user is not logged in, the browser takes the user to the login page. Once the user logs in using this process, the system displays this landing page. If the landing page was created in an enterprise account, the user's enterprise ID must match the enterprise ID of the user who published the landing page in order to access it.
- Application Page - Chosing this option makes the page available to be a custom tab. This option must be configured by contacting your ExactTarget represtentative.